# How can I create integers based on a button's location (column, row)?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am trying to make a multiplication table made of buttons with the math fact on them that changes to the product when pressed, then returned to the fact when pressed again. Got the first part but can't figure out how to get it to return to the original button setting. I have my program constructed in 2 classes. First makes the buttons and populates them with original facts. Used nested loop to write the text (math facts) on the buttons.

```
    import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;


    public class Grid {
        public static void main(String args[]){

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grid Layout");
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(600, 600);
            frame.setResizable(false);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new GridLayout (9, 9, 5, 5));
          panel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

            int i, j;
            for (i = 1; i<=9; i++){
            for (j = 1; j <= 9; j++){
                FactButton button =new FactButton();
                button.setText(i + " x " + j);
                panel.add(button);
                }       
            }
            frame.add(panel);
            }


            }
```

Second class defines what buttons do when pressed. I made two cases. The first is the default, second changes the button to present product. This works fine when pressed the first time. When button is pressed a second time I get error messages and nothing changes. Can I change my first case to integers based on 
the button's location on the panel (column, row)? How do I do this? Other suggestions?

```
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;



    public class FactButton extends JButton implements ActionListener{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public FactButton() {
            this.addActionListener(this);
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String prob = this.getText();

            String left = prob.substring(0, prob.indexOf(" "));
            String right = prob.substring(prob.indexOf(" ")+3, prob.length()     );
            int i = Integer.parseInt(left); 
            int j = Integer.parseInt(right); 

            int v=0;
            v++;
            v%=2;
            switch(v){
            case 0:
                this.setText(null);
                break; 
            case 1:     
                this.setText(i*j+"");
                this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                this.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                this.setOpaque(true);
                break;

            }
        }
     }
```

It switches to the product on first press. Breaks on second. Thought it would go back to a blank button. How can I get it to show the original math fact?

Answer (score 3):

Keep the numbers inside `FactButton` as members. Then you can use them whenever you want. In the current situation you are parsing numbers from the button text. But after first click text of the button is changing. So you are losing the numbers which set during instantiation.

Change your `FactButton` with this:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class FactButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    private final static int PRODUCT_STATE = 0;
    private final static int FACT_STATE = 1;

    private int buttonState = FACT_STATE;

    private int firstNumber;
    private int secondNumber;

    public FactButton(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
        this.setText(firstNumber + " x " + secondNumber);
        this.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        switch (buttonState) {
        case PRODUCT_STATE:
            this.setText(firstNumber + " x " + secondNumber);
            this.setBackground(null);
            this.setContentAreaFilled(true);

            buttonState = FACT_STATE;
            break;
        case FACT_STATE:
            this.setText(firstNumber * secondNumber + "");
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            this.setOpaque(true);
            buttonState = PRODUCT_STATE;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And do not set button's text after instantiation. Do it like this:

```
FactButton button =new FactButton(i, j);
//not needed
//button.setText(i + " x " + j);
panel.add(button);
```

Comment: This is another relevant option :)

Comment: I"ll try this one too. You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Answer is here :)

First of all, your thing with the switch is very messy, so i corrected it using regex: it checks if the text is only a number or something else, so if its on the form "64" or "8 x 8" by example

In your case, i won't be using column and row. Imagine you suddenly added a row or something... You should use HashMap, by setting the default value of every button in it, like this:

**Grid.java** :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Grid {

        static HashMap<JButton, String> map = new HashMap<JButton, String>();

        public static void main(String args[]){

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grid Layout");

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(800, 800);
                frame.setResizable(false);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new GridLayout (9, 9, 5, 5));
              panel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

                int i, j;
                for (i = 1; i<=9; i++){
                    for (j = 1; j <= 9; j++){
                        FactButton button =new FactButton();
                        String txt = i + " x " + j;
                        button.setText(txt);
                        map.put(button, txt);
                        panel.add(button);
                    }       
                }
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        public static String getOriginalFromButton(JButton button){
            return map.get(button);
        }
}
```

**FactButton.java**:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

    public class FactButton extends JButton implements ActionListener{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public FactButton() {
            this.addActionListener(this);
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String prob = this.getText();

            int i = 0,j = 0;

            if(!prob.matches("-?\\d+")){//it was on the "x*y" form
                String left = prob.substring(0, prob.indexOf(" "));
                String right = prob.substring(prob.indexOf(" ")+3, prob.length());
                i = Integer.parseInt(left); 
                j = Integer.parseInt(right);

                this.setText(i*j+"");
                this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                this.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                this.setOpaque(true);
            } else {//so it was on the form of a number
                this.setText(Grid.getOriginalFromButton(this));
                //any other changes like color
            }
        }
     }
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Whoo, hoo! Works. Doesn't return to original button color, but no errors! Thanks. Baby's first (on-tutorial) coding project. Bound to be messy. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message is occuring because of this line;

```
String right = prob.substring(prob.indexOf(" ")+3, prob.length()     );
```

If the result is shown, let's say it's `42`, `prob.indexOf(" ")` returns `-1`, therefore it's equivalent to `prob.substring(2, 2);` Since `42` is only 2 characters long, you can't reach it's `2`nd index, which would be the 3rd letter. Also, I don't think that

```
int v=0;
v++;
v%=2;
```

is doing much. v always be `1`

---

The simplest solution to your problem would be to just parse the original text to the `FactButton` constructor. You might also want to use a [`JToggleButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html) instead of a `JButton` to let it show it's state.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Grid {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grid Layout");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(600, 600);
                frame.setResizable(false);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 9, 5, 5));

                int i, j;
                for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                    for (j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
                        FactButton button = new FactButton(i + " x " + j);
                        panel.add(button);
                    }
                }
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}

class FactButton extends JToggleButton {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String orgText;

    public FactButton(String orgText) {
        this.orgText = orgText;
        setText(orgText);
        addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    String prob = getText();

                    String left = prob.substring(0, prob.indexOf(" "));
                    String right = prob.substring(prob.indexOf(" ") + 3, prob.length());
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(left);
                    int j = Integer.parseInt(right);
                    setText(i * j + "");
                } else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
                    setText(orgText);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this is not a solution to keep using JButton, but it could have been good in another case...

Comment: @Cukic0d Could you explain why it's not good to use a `JToggleButton` in this case?

Comment: That's fine :) but not what he asked... he asked how to get "8 x 8" for instance, from "64"